# Is it possible to place a point at a coordinate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates

Is it possible to place a point at a coordinate in qgis?

I have a map, using irish grid reference and wish to place a point at an exact 6 digit coordinate. Is it possible to do it.

Previous to this i have placed the point roughly and then moved it whilst zoomed to the exact location, surely there is an easier way.

Comment: Use the 'Numerical Vertex Edit' plugin. [See this answer for details.](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63114/how-to-manually-edit-point-coordinates-in-qgis)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can place a point at exact coordinates.  There are a couple of ways you can do this.  One is interactively by digitizing a point and then, while still in edit mode select the "Numerical Vertex Edit" button at the right hand end of the edit toolbar.  You highlight a point and then type in the location in the popup box.

The other way, if you have several points is to make a CSV file in Notepad (say) and import that using the "Add Delimited Text Layer" button.

Comment: Numerical Vertex Edit is a plugin so this will need to be added first before you can do this above. You can also use the NumericalDigitize Plugin to digitize the point in the first place.

Comment: Deadly.  Installed the plugin and it is perfect.

Comment: I tried to use this method but the tool remains greyed out. Point layer is in edit mode and the feature is selected. QGis 2.8.2 Wien

Comment: Is your layer also selected (highlighted) in the layers list as well as being in edit mode?  If not the Numerical digitize button will be greyed out. The only other thing is, make sure you are not confusing the 'Numerical Vertex Edit' button with the very similar 'Trace edit' button, which would also be greyed out for a point layer. Otherwise, I am not sure what to suggest as this plugin works well for me in the same version of QGIS as you are using and I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just in case there is somebody that hase the same experience with me. I took some time trying to find Numerical Vertex Edit Icon. Finally, I got the answer here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63114/how-to-manually-edit-point-coordinates-in-qgis