# QGIS - move a point object to specific coordinate

Tags: qgis

Is there a way of select an object (point, polygon) and move it to a specific coordinate (manually inserted)?

(with Numerical Digitize plugin can not make a move of the object but rather it creates me a new object)

Comment: Off the top of my head you should be able to do this with the "Numerical vertex edit" plugin, but i am not totally sure.

Comment: You are right, the Numerical Vertex Edit solve the problem.

thanks

Answer (score 11):

With QGIS 2.18 onward this is now in core for editing points.

You need to have the vertex editor panel visible.

But once you start editing nodes, you can type in the x and y for them.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find vertex editor panel under View/Panels, but it showed up after I went to edit nodes mode and clicked a node.

Answer (score 1):

The "Vertex Editor" panel shows up only upon click with **right mouse button** on vertices that are in Edit mode and the Node Tool is selected - otherwise you will not see this panel.