# On QGIS, how can I relocate some of the points that are in incorrect location on map?

Tags: qgis, point, geocoding

I have created a map that is geocoded. When I viewed the final result, I noticed that some points are placed at an incorrect location on the map. I tried to change the location of the points by updating the latitude and longitude values in table of contents, however the points did not relocate. I even updated the addresses in the table of contents, but still it did not help. How can I move them to a right place on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS toolbar click on toggle editing (pencil) and edit your layer. Move points with Move feature tool (three dots with an arrow), and save changes.

Comment: Is there a way to move to a certain coordinates?

Comment: Yes with the vertex tool (a point with two lines and two tools) and vertex editor panel, click with right mouse button, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92466/qgis-move-a-point-object-to-specific-coordinate.