# Numerical Vertex Edit Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to shift a point to a specific location. 
I have followed the instructions here: [How to manually edit point coordinates in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63114/how-to-manually-edit-point-coordinates-in-qgis) 
but got this error code:

> An error has occurred while executing Python code:
>
> QgsCsException: forward transform of (9675.040722, 120072.456618)
>   PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
>   +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=utm +zone=56 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

I entered 0554339, 6879645.
OTF is turned on.
The layer CRS is GDA94/MGA 56

Answer (score 3):

Are your project & layer both in the same CRS? I just tested your coordinates using the following method:
Set Project CRS to GDA94/MGA zone 56.
Create a new point shapefile layer (I am assuming your layer is a shapefile).
Toggle editing on point layer > click Add feature > create a new point feature in zone 56 (I just dropped it in a random location in south east Queensland).
With editing still toggled on, go to Numerical Vertex Edit plugin under Edit menu to activate the point selection tool and click on the point you wish to move.
Enter the new coordinates in the dialog box. I entered 554339,6879645 exactly as shown with no spaces.
This worked for me with no error message and placed the point just south of Tweed Heads.

Comment: Thanks @Ben W. My problem was the space between the easting and northing.