# Add data to an attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a shapefile (points) and would like to add points using the attribute table and not the Add Feature tool at the main screen.

I went over the questions here, but didn't find a similar problem to mine.

Comment: Also, I tried to add the feature (a point) using the Add Feature and then replace the X,Y at the attribute table. But the point remains where I drew it and didn't re locate to the X Y I gave it at the attribute table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the easiest way to do this is through a combination of the Add Feature tool and Identify. Though you cannot add data from the attribute table, you can add features near where you're trying to place. And through the identify tool, figure out where exactly it is. From there, you can use the the Numeric Vertex Edit Plugin to move it exactly.

This question may be also able to help: [Is it possible to place a point at a coordinate in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46847/is-it-possible-to-place-a-point-at-a-coordinate-in-qgis)

Answer (score 3):

The question is not clear, well trying to answer with what i got..

1)First create a new shapefile of which you have the XY and its attribute using this operation
 "Vector ---> XY tools ---> Open Excel file as attribute table or point layer"

2)Then Merge the shapefile which you already have have and the newly created one into one shapefile, this can be done by the following steps
 "Vector ---> Mergeshapes"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The data in the attribute table has nothing to do with the coordinates of a point.

You can add points with `Add delimited text` using columns for X and Y, but afterwards you can move those points without any changes in the attribute table.

This sounds a bit absurd, but for lines and polygons, it has little use to store the complete geometry in the attribute table. Consequently, the geometry information for points is also not stored there.

In GIS databases (postgis, spatialite or shapefile), the geometry is stored in a sepearate geometry column, which is hidden by most GIS software.

If you want the point coordinates as readable text, use the Export geometry part of the MMQGIS plugin.